# How to pass actionScript 2 value to php

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I have decompiled a flash game. There is a variable called `totalscore`. I need to send this variable to my `leaderboard.php`. How can I do this in secure.

Currently I'm passing the value like this.

```
getURL("mydomain.com/leaderboard.php&value="+totalscore,'_top','get');
```

I have accessed above value like this:

### leaderboard.php

```
$totalscore = $_GET['value'];
```

But this method is not secure. Because any one can change the value an press enter. then value of 'value' will store in the db.

I tried using `POST METHOD`  on `actionscript`. But it not worked.

Please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Before you continue, you should know that there is absolutely no way to make the data you send from Flash to PHP secure.

Comment: @MartyWallace Is there any method to pass value using POST method on getURL()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LoadVars` which has [`send()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as2/reference/flashlite/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118ccf9c47f-7da6.html) and [`sendAndLoad()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as2/reference/flashlite/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118ccf9c47f-7da5.html) methods.

The third argument of both of these lets you determine the method you want to use to send the data (GET or POST). Example:

```
var vars:LoadVars = new LoadVars();
vars.value = totalScore;
vars.send("mydomain.com/leaderboard.php", "_blank", "POST");
```

Comment: can you give me the code here? because i'm not good in AS in at all. :( how to use send() methods?

Comment: @user1711599 Added a code sample. Is there a reason you're learning AS2 instead of AS3?

Comment: I have decompiled a game. It is in AS2. that's why. I have implemented this game on facebook. ur method is working on direct url. But, it's not working on facebook. :(

this is my code in AS2

var vars:LoadVars = new LoadVars();
 vars.value = totalscore;
 vars.send("https://apps.facebook.com/avicricket/?view=leaderboard", "_top", "POST");

page.php

if(isset($_POST['value'])){
 echo "value set ".$_POST['value'];
}else{
echo "not set";
}

any idea?

Comment: i tried with 'target' as '_self', '_top', '_parent'. still not solve the problem.

Comment: @user1711599 Use `sendAndLoad()` instead. Documentation and examples are found if you click the link I attached to it in my answer.

Comment: i'll try with that. what is the reason not to work with 'send()'? this is the way i'm accessing value in php. $_POST['value']. is this right?

Comment: can't we use javascript instead of php? it's also good. then i can update my DB using ajax. if you know how to do that place the code. super thanks for the help.